# How can I export object's field schema information to excel?

Tags: data-loader, fields, schema

How can I export the fields of an object from Salesforce into an Excel sheet? I'm only looking for the field schema information, not the objects records.

Comment: I mean Download or Extract

Comment: Has anyone found a solution to export the field label, api name, type, help text, created by, created date, last modified by, last modified date? a file with the label, api and created information would be the minimum needed info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a free App for such an export but unfortunately it seems reported broken and removed from public app exchange:

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000018leZEAQ

Try it. If you get it to run, it provides you a nice list with type information, label, api name, length, etc

We have also developed an sumilar App to read the field schema information, but jet not released an without excel export at this time. If 'easy describe' won't be fixed, I'll consider to release our app as private managed package.

If you just need the Api-Names, use any of the mentioned dataloaders. I would recommend workbench https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php . Make an export limited to 1 row. In excel delete the lone data row and preserve only the first header row containing your field names. In excel there is an function to covert columns in rows. Use it and you have your list.

An other dirty trick is: go to the setup and your object and then to your field list. Mark it, copy it and paste it to excel. Won't be perfect but could be a start.

Comment: For what its worth 'Etherios EasyDescribe' linked to from above only seems to work with standard objects - I don't think it can handle custom objects.  Apart from that it seems great though.

Answer (score 13):

The best thing I came across is https://schemalister.herokuapp.com/. No installation required since it is hosted as a Heroku app.

Answer (score 3):

install extension called salesforce inspector and from there export the field information using below query.

```sql
SELECT QualifiedApiName, DeveloperName, Description, DataType, LastModifiedById, LastModifiedDate 
FROM FieldDefinition 
WHERE EntityDefinition.DeveloperName='Account'
```

Add object api name for which you want this details and click export. It will give you the all the details about the fields in the specific object.

Answer (score 1):

Use an app called [Field Dumper](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EJg2hUAD) (but it can't or won't pull the description field)

Or a nifty browser extension called [Salesforce Inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-inspector/aodjmnfhjibkcdimpodiifdjnnncaafh/related)

Answer (score 0):

There are different tools which will help you to get the fields name in excel from object.(I think this is called export).

for example, Apex DataLoader this tool helps you to import as well as export. (if you have many fields to type their api name then this will allow you to select all fields.)

another same tool is Force.com Explorer.

I hope this might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use Heroku app, https://www.dfeldt-describe.com

- No install required (uses OAuth2 to authenticate against your org)
- Works for Sandbox and Production
- View/Extract all object metadata available from sfdc's rest api
- Extracts full object metadata to an excel workbook (including all picklists)
- No limits issues on # of objects in your schema

Answer (score -1):

Depending on what it is you are actually looking for you could technically go to the Object and Highlight, Copy, and Paste the fields and their API names... really depends on how much information you are truly looking for from them.